# What is the default value for not initialized variables in C++?

Tags: c++

Below, you see a very very simple program :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int r;
    int c;
    int d;

    cout<<"r="<<r<<endl<<"c="<<c<<endl<<"d="<<d;
    return 0;
}
```

The question is , why in the output the value of `c` is different from the value of `r` and `d`?

[image]

When I change the order of them in printing on the screen, the value change!

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int r;
    int c;
    int d;

    cout<<"c="<<c<<endl<<"r="<<r<<endl<<"d="<<d;    

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Why this time the value of `r` is different from the others? I just change the order of printing them on the screen!

Comment: it will be any value in the memory.

Comment: **undefined** behaviour ([as indicated by Clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8ed3bdbd8188089a))

Comment: Which is why I always initialise auto r = int().  It'll be zero.

Comment: To answer your edit, >>> **undefined** <<< behaviour

Comment: Couldn't help but notice the date in your screenshots. 3/29/15 <-- undefined behavior --> just like the output of your program

Comment: Is your question more how does it get that "undefined value"? or perhaps is that value left there by previous program?

Comment: @sam2090 What's wrong with the date? I didn't got the point!

Comment: I can't recognize the text in your screen shot.  Can you right click on the title bar, select "mark", highlight the text, press Enter, then paste the text into your question?

Comment: @Abraham, today, in the U.S., the PST date is 3/27/15.  The 29th hasn't happened yet.

Comment: @GRC Is that value left by the previous program really? Is this safe? Shouldn't OS make it zero at the end of the programs?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Oops! 27?!! I thought the maximum different is 1 day! It seems we have 2 days ahead of you! ;) BTW tomorrow it will rain! :D

Comment: @Abraham I don't want to move get off-topic but the world's furthest time is in Kiribati and even there it is still 3/28/2015.

Comment: @sam2090 Oh! You are right! It is 3/28/2015 in my computer now! I don't have any idea why the captured pictures show 29!

Comment: @Abraham undefined behavior :). just like the problem you are facing with the code. since you didn't initialize the variables, you will not have any idea where the resulting output came from? hope it helps understand the problem

Comment: @sam2090 btw, both fixed now! :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the default value for not initialized variables in C++

The default value is indeterminate for local variables of fundamental types.

> The question is , why in the output the value of c is different from the value of r and d?

Because reading uninitialized variable has undefined behaviour.

> When I change the order of variables in cout line, the value changes!

If you're surprised by this, then you've not understood yet what undefined behaviour or unspecified value means.

The value of your uninitialized values can be anything and any change to your code, the change of compiler, the change of processor even the altitude of moon* may change the garbage. Or it might not. In this case it did.

* not very likely a feature in most c++ compilers

Comment: Would you please take another look at the question?  I updated it. When I change the order of variables in `cout` line, the value changes! I accepted the answer, but if you have any other info, please add. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Values of uninitialized variables declared in a function is undefined.

Global variables will be set to 0 (or equivalent if it's not a number).